# What are the repeatedly used structures in 4-character expressions (e.g. chengyu) and what do they mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, chengyu

In [today's reading](https://www.sohu.com/a/404432892_120685201?scm=1002.44003c.17c024e.PC_ARTICLE_REC&spm=smpc.content.fd-d.3.1595225010020UuwenVD&_f=index_pagerecom_3), I encountered the expression [敬而远之](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%95%AC%E8%80%8C%E8%BF%9C%E4%B9%8B).  However, I noticed this `x而y之` structure is repeated in many other 4-character expressions (Pleco search `?而?之`):

```
敬而远之
大而化之
等而下之
分而治之
换而言之
久而久之
取而代之
堂而皇之
```

Thus, it seems I should study how such structures work and thereby learn whole families of 4-character expressions at a time.

**Question**: What are the repeatedly used structures in 4-character expressions (e.g. chengyu) and what do they mean?

I'm seeking a kind of overview of major structures (those that occur in multiple 4-character expressions, like `x而y之` above) for 4-character expressions, and a brief explanation as to how to interpret them.  It looks like `x而y之` is an adjective that combines `x` and `y`.

Note that `x而y之` is just one example, and there are others like `千x万y` (see also [Chengyu with two numbers](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/chengyu-with-two-numbers)).

(Whenever I look up chengyu on the web, I find pages like [this](https://speechling.com/blog/guide-to-chinese-idioms-and-chengyu/) and [this](https://www.travelchinacheaper.com/chinese-idioms) which give a handful of common but disparate examples, making them very difficult to actually remember.)

Comment: Related: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/32158/is-%e4%b8%8d-a-%e4%b8%8d-b-a-grammatical-structure-like-%e5%8f%88-a-%e5%8f%88-b

Comment: I just found others:X 而不 Y.

Comment: Related: [Words related to several 成语 (via 《AB》 → 《-A-B》)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/33590/words-related-to-several-%e6%88%90%e8%af%ad-via-ab-%e2%86%92-a-b)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there are two types of 成语 represented by the same “structure”.

> A而B之 could mean “action + action, done to something (third person pronoun)”.

取而代之 means “to take and replace 之 (something that was previously mentioned)”. Compare this to 取代, which simply means “replace”. You could consider 取而代之 a literary form of 取代; using it adds elegance to an otherwise common word. Other examples include 换而言之、敬而远之 and 分而治之.

> A而B之 could also mean “adjective + adjective, used to describe something (third person pronoun)”.

堂而皇之 means that something (之) is “wide like a hall and grand like imperial edifices”. Similarly, this can be considered a literary form of 堂皇. I would say 久而久之 has similar characteristics, but note that the 久 is describing **a long period of time**, instead of the appearance or a quality of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Axel Tong answered A而B之 perfectly. I would address some other idiom structures not mentioned in the question

Becky 李蓓 wrote:

> Note that x而y之 is just one example, and there are others like 千x万y

1. [(adjective A) + (noun A) + (adjective B) + (noun B)] / Example: 千丝万缕，如狼似虎
2. [(adverb A) + (adjective A) + (adverb B) + (adjective B)] / Example: 穷凶极恶，巨奸大恶
3. [adverb A] + [(verb A) + (adverb B) + (verb B)] / Example: 穷追猛打，虚打假闘
4. [(verb A) + (adverb A) + (verb B) + (adverb B)] / Example: 赶尽杀绝，看惯见熟

In the four structures above, the relationship between (A) and (B) are either being similar or being one half of a split-up compound word

千万 丝缕 --> 千丝万缕

如似 狼虎 --> 如狼似虎

穷极 凶恶 --> 穷凶极恶

巨大 奸恶 --> 巨奸大恶

穷猛 追打 --> 穷追猛打

虚假 打闘 --> 虚打假闘

赶杀 尽绝 --> 赶尽杀绝

看见 惯熟 --> 看惯见熟

Studying the examples about, you can apply the same structure to coin new idiomatic phrases out of the common compound words that contain two characters that have a similar, identical or opposite meaning

Example:

粉碎 身(体) 骨(骼) --> 粉身碎骨

超赶 英美 --> 超英赶美

忽然 冷热 --> 忽冷忽热